# Angular 2 bundle size increased after AOT

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-aot

I am trying to implement AOT is a large Angular 2 app. I am using tsc to compile and webpack to bundle. Bundle size should be reduced after AOT but it increased instead. I am unable to understand why.

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom_typings.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  },
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  }
}
```

**webpack config loader**

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'], exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e|async)\.ts$/] },
```

**main.aot.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';

if ('production' === process.env.ENV) {
    enableProdMode();
}
import {AppModuleNgFactory} from '../compiled/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';
import {KeycloakService} from './app/keycloak/keycloak';

KeycloakService.init().then(
    o => {
        platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
    },
    x => {
        window.location.reload();
    }
);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use Rollout , as it offers a feature called tree shaking. "Tree Shaking can greatly reduce the downloaded size of the application by removing unused portions of both source and library code. In fact, most of the reduction in small apps comes from removing unreferenced Angular features." Follow this guide -> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: @Alexus So implementing AOT without rollup will not result in any size reduction?

Comment: AOT replaces HTML templates by JavaScript code. The JS code is longer than the HTML. But it also allows removing the angular compiler from the bundle (assuming it's the same bundle). That reduces the bundle size. Depending on the number of HTML templates and their size, the bundle size can be reduced or increased. The more templates you have, the more chances there are that your bundle will be larger than without AOT.